# Fixed position for content of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wrote simple iOS app which countdown the time til midnight. I have single text label which is used to display current time. I use NStimer to change the content of that label. The problem is that when the content of the label is  changed (in every second)the content moves left and right for about 1px. Is it possible the position of label content to be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of a label is fixed, make sure the text alignment isn't on center.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make sure this never happens by always showing the time in HH:MM:SS format. Something like 01:11:05 etc. Make sure you override the text alignment and the minimumfontsize function to match the current font size